# Updated div.banner-container only displaying on Sharepoint for myself

Tags: 2007

I've updated the div.banner-container style using SharePoint Designer 2007. Additionally, I've checked out, saved, and checked in the master page template. I then went and approved that page so that it should be published out to everybody. Additionally, I selected "Apply Style" for the banner.

However, I'm still the only user that sees this new banner on our SharePoint front page. Is there somewhere else I should be changing permissions/applying update/approving/etc.?

This is a SP 2007 environment.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check-in and publish a **major** version?

Comment: Yes, I did that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to updating the master page I also need to update and publish the .css style sheet. Once I did this the problem was resolved.

Thanks for your help Kit!